# Coreplot Graph Label Not Consistent

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, label, core-plot

Bear with me on this one. I have been creating my iphone app on both my macbook, and also a Mac VM which I'm renting as I cannot use the latest SDK on my own macbook.

So, coreplot has been working perfectly. I noticed before that when I transferred my Xcode project to the VM, for some reason the Axis Labels weren't showing the correct offset. So I changed them. Vice versa, if I transfer my Xcode project back to my own macbook the Axis titles are again not offset correctly.

In the end I finished developing the app on the VM and uploaded it to the store. I thought everything would be fine as the emulator on the VM showed the graphs the way I wanted them.

However after my app was successfully uploaded to the store I downloaded it, and Voila the axis offset is wrong, just like the way it was when I switched my project To/From the VM and my macbook.

Here is what I've been trying to describe-

**VM Simulator**

[image]

**App downloaded from Store, or simulator from my macbook**

[image]

My questions is obviously why is this happening and how can I fix it?

**TLDR; What looks right on my macbook simulator looks wrong on VM simulator and vice versa**

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using? Do both versions of the app use the same version of Core Plot?

Comment: The versions may have been different, I think I originally used 1.0 or 1.1, but used 1.2 on the VM. But my point is, if I changed the offset so that it looked right on the VM, submitted it to the apple store using the VM, why is it now different when downloaded? Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

As highlighted above by 'Undo', the reason for this happening was due to the different Coreplot versions I was using. I simply uninstalled Coreplot 1.2 on the VM, and installed version 1.0.

All worked fine then.